# NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column could not find table with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

*I mention my script files below*

My script is ok before my app is doing interaction. Once, I dropped myschema in mysql workbench for my badly reason and do a successfully create which they are no tables in the last time for twice. I run my script again for refill and Pycharm says:

<sup>Flask: sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column "a.b_id"  could not find table "myschema.b" with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'</sup>

I checked my mistmatch syntax for sure and fixed anything thats relevant with ForeignKey constructor in here. People who make a support for me, I think something wrong in my app ?

ps: when the first I fixed with adding **table_args**={'extend-existing':True} and I remember that the schema name was done in the end.

**config.py**

```
class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = 'mylongsecretkey'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "mysql+pymysql://root:%s@localhost/myschema?charset=utf8mb4" % quote(
        'mypassword@2')
    SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        'clinic_alternative': "mysql+pymysql://root:%s@localhost/myschema?charset=utf8mb4" % quote(
            'mypassword@2')
    }
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
```

****init**.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from app.config import Config
from app.register.main import register_bp
from app.database import db

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db.init_app(app)
```

**database.py**

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
db = SQLAlchemy()
```

**app/models.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from app.database import db

class A(db.Model):
  __table_name__:str = 'table_a'
  __table_args__ = {'extend-existing': True, 'schema': 'myschema'}
  id = Colunm(Interger, primary_key=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
  attribute1 = Colunm(String(255), nullable=False)
  attribute2 = relationship('app.models.B', backref='a', uselist=False)

class B(db.Model):
  __table_name__:str = 'table_b'
  __table_args__ = {'extend-existing': True, 'schema': 'myschema'}
  id = Colunm(Integer, ForeignKey('myschema.table_a.id'), primary_key=True, nullable=False,         unique=True)
  attribute1 = Colunm(String(255), nullable=False) 

if __name__ = '__main__':
  from app import app
  with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```